# I'm trying to write a function for postgresql to do some string manipulation

Tags: postgresql, function, string, syntax

The purpose of the function is to take a string and, if it contains parens, delete everything in the parens. Here's what I have:

```
CREATE FUNCTION clearmethodparams(IN qname text) RETURNS text AS
  $BODY$        
  IF position($o$($o$ in qname) = 0 THEN
    return qname;
  ELSE 
    return substring(qname from 0 for position($p$($p$ in qname)) || $c$)$c$;
  END IF;
  $BODY$
LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE;
```

The error it keeps giving me is

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IF"
>   LINE 3: IF position($o$($o$ in qname) = 0
>   THEN

I've been trying to find some good documentation on function syntax, but nothing so far has been helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "convert" the function from an [SQL function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html) to a [PL/pgSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html) one - replace "LANGUAGE sql" with "LANGUAGE plpgsql" in your CREATE FUNCTION statement. Also you will need to "wrap" your code in a proper [block](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-structure.html).

OTOH you could probably achieve the same with an SQL function, e.g. with some clever user of [`CASE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#AEN15488) or similar.

Comment: Thanks, Milen, but it's still giving the same error after your edit... WAIT I got it - I just needed BEGIN and END statements too. THANKS!!!

Comment: Oh, yes - I'll add that bit for future reference.